# How to replace every line by \n

Tags: android, string, flutter, dart, uitextfield

I have a TextField and bellow of the TextField there is a Card and Text as child,The child of the Card display the String that entered in TextField, I want to replace every line by \n, How can I do this?

Example:

Text entered :

```
Hello

World
```

result :

```
Hello

World
```

expected :

```
Hello\nWorld
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this it will work.

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String s = "Hello\nHello";
        System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\n","\\\\n"));
     }

}
```

It is a plain java code but you can use the same function replaceAll in android as well and instead of S.O.P use setText().

Comment: Thanks it worked but instead of "\\\\n" I used "\\n"

Comment: I want to know why the question is tagged as 'Dart' and 'Flutter', and the accepted answer is in Java... ?

Comment: @JulioHenriqueBitencourt This answer solved my problem and all I want from this answer is `.replaceAll("\n","\\\\n")` which is common between Dart and Java

Answer (score 1):

Save the input in a string. Now check each character and store it in another string but when you encounter a *next line* or "\n" then append the string with "\"+"n". Keep checking till you encounter the end of string or null. You can also run a loop till sizeof(string). 
This new string will be your expected output.